# jQuery on click, add class but also remove if the class is already present

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a nav menu that needs to trigger with clicks rather than hovers. When the links are clicked, an `.open` class would be added to the parent `li`. If that parent already has the `.open` class, then it would get removed. It would also be removed if another link is clicked on. So far I can get the class added when clicked and removed when a sibling is clicked, but not removed when it's already `.open`.

I tried adding a `hasClass` conditional, but that didn't work either. Seemed like it reruns the function every time it's clicked and therefore ignores the hasClass conditional.

Can anyone provide help? I tried `toggleClass`, but that didn't work.

```js
$('li a').on('click', function() {
    $('li a').parent().removeClass('open');
    $(this).parent().addClass('open');
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.open {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Item 1</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Check if parent has the open class then do what you need based on the result, there is a hasClass function https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

Comment: I tried that, but it wouldn't work. Seemed like it reruns the function every time it's clicked and therefore ignores the hasClass conditional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do what you require you can use `toggleClass()` on the parent `li` when the element is clicked. To remove the class from all other `li` elements you can use `removeClass()` along with `not()` to exclude the current `li`. Try this:

```js
$('li a').on('click', function() {
  let $li = $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
  $('li').not($li).removeClass('open');
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.open {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Item 1</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

1. jquery toggleClass() to toggle yellow highlight (.open css class) on click/unclicking the same link.
2. jquery siblings() to remove .open class on all the other li items.

Below is the link for the demo

https://jsfiddle.net/so1u8hq6/

```js
$('li a').on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open');
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.open {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Item 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but, after seeing the provided answers and some of the CSS you use I had to urge with my suggestions:

- UX. **Avoid styling LI tags** in general, or at least set the desired `display` and move on. **Style directly the `a` tag** (with the necessary paddings etc.). You'll not only get less CSS to take care of, but also a **larger touch interaction area**. Makes no sense to style something *yellow* if it's not a UI part of something interactable. Also in JS, you don't need to take care about the `LI` *wrappers* any more - but only about the actual `A` Elements.
- **Don't use common selectors** like `$('li a')` - those might target *any* LI→A elements in your app. Instead **be more specific** and use a Class like i.e: `.tabs` for the parent `UL`. Both in CSS and JS.
- Try to **use Event Delegation** (in jQuey using the `.on()` method). Not only it will help you to catch the `Event.delegateTarget` parent `UL` where needed, but also the `this` (the clicked element), but mainly reference all the *"group"* of  `a` elements enclosed in the common parent. That way you can have **as many `.tabs` in a single page** as you like. And yes, thanks to Event delegation you can even **add dynamically LI Elements** - and your JS will still work as expected.
- Since you're using `<a href="#">` Anchor elements, instead of (more properly) `<button type="button>"` Elements, you need to also use `Event.preventDefault()` in order to prevent the browser its default behavior and that's to follow anchors (scroll the page, navigate, etc...)
- Use the selector `"a.open"` when you want to target and remove the `"open"` class. By *just* using `"a"` (or in other answers on this page - `"li"`) you're uselessly *touching* elements trying to remove a class  that's not there in the first place.

Finally, here's the CSS retouch and the proper jQuery needed for your task:

```js
$(".tabs").on("click", "a", function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  $("a.open", ev.delegateTarget).not(this).removeClass("open");
  $(this).toggleClass("open");
});
```

```css
.tabs {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Style your Anchors, not the dummy LI wrappers */
.tabs a      { padding: 10px; }
.tabs a.open { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To explain the only complicated line:

```js
$(
  "a.open",             // Target just the ones (if any) of class "open"
  ev.delegateTarget     // inside the common ".tabs" ancestor
)
  .not(this)            // ... not the clicked element (since later we'll use .toggleClass on it)
  .removeClass("open"); // ... remove that class "open"
```

the rest is pretty self explanatory.

Further read:

- [jQuery Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation)
- [jQuery event.delegateTarget](https://api.jquery.com/event.delegatetarget/)
- [Event.preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Answer (score -1):

So you only want the yellow background to appear as a signifier of user interaction rather than for the background color to be displayed? Have you tried using the **mousedown/mouseup** functions instead of `.on('click', function(){...}`?

I was able to simulate the click event where the color showcases via this method:

```js
$('li a').mousedown(function() {
  $('li a').parent().removeClass('open');
    $(this).parent().addClass('open');
});
$('li a').mouseup(function() {
  $('li a').parent().removeClass('open');
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.open {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Item 1</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: No, the background needs to stay yellow -- basically it'll trigger an "open" state where a list of sub-nav items would appear below. The `open` class would change that sub-nav's display from `none` to `block`. I'm working with existing code, so I can't change their hierarchy very much.